# Почему Django view функция по ajax не хочет работать с киррилическим текстом(живой поиск)?

Tags: python, ajax, django, unicode, django-rest-framework

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
   def live_search(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
   key = request.data['key']
   result = Event.objects.filter(title__istartswith=key)
   events = serializers.serialize('json', result)
   print (key)
   print (result)
   data = {
  'events': events,

}
return Response(data)
```

Поиск по первым буквам ключа возвращает правильные значения если key на английском если на русском почему-то возвращает [] хотя там должны быть совпадения. раньше вроде работало, непонятно в какой-момент сломалось . локально litsql . в продавшее postgresql

Че это может быть?

Comment: Может попробовать в случае, если возвращается пустой результат, сделать `key = key.encode('iso-8859-1')`, после чего это значение подсунуть в поиск? Либо `key = key.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8‌​')`

Comment: @German that leads to internal server error..